# What is causing automatic status change after placing order through a webservice api in Prestashop?

Tags: web-services, prestashop, status

I have successfuly made a new order through Prestashop webservice api. What is causing me problem is order's current_status which is somehow automatically changed to 12 (*Payment remotely accepted*) everytime order is placed.

I can't figure out what is the reason for this because I set it to 10 (*Awaiting bankwire payment*) and it is still set to 10 in a response I get after making POST request. But if I check it in the back-office, in database or through api, order has status 12 now.

Any idea what is causing that change?

Comment: I have used this as a workaroud: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489152/how-to-update-order-status-in-prestashop-via-webservice-api

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop automatically adds order status "remote payment accepted" to orders added via web service. Alternatively, you can add order status via web service after you add order.

Please consider following code:

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/order_histories?schema=blank'));

$xml->order_history->id_order = $id['order'];
$xml->order_history->id_order_state = '3';

$opt = array('resource' => 'order_histories');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
```

This way it will change status to Processing in Progress. You will also need to disable remote payment accepted validation and email feature.